# Getting the wrong parameters when adding a click event to a div element with appendChild(iDiv)

Tags: javascript, fetch, appendchild

I'm trying to add a click event to a div element with appendChild(iDiv), but I get the wrong parameters.

This is my code:

```
function showHand() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/showHandPlayer1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            for (z = 0; z < data.length; z++) {
                console.log(z);
                var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
                iDiv.id = 'card'+z;
                iDiv.innerHTML = data[z] + ' - ' + z;
                iDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {playCard(z)}, false); 
                document.getElementById('hand').appendChild(iDiv);
            }
        });
}
function playCard(i) {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/playCard/'+i)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
        console.log(data + " is played.");
    });
```

fetch is returning a list [ "Yellow0", "Red5", "RedDirection", "ChangeCollor" ]

This is the result in the inspector:

[image]

In the console I get this error:

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

TypeError: x is null
uno.html:22:4
Forespørgsel til fremmed websted blokeret: Politikken for samme oprindelse tillader ikke læsning af fjernressourcen http://127.0.0.1:5000/playCard/4. (Årsag: CORS-headeren 'Access-Control-Allow-    Origin' findes ikke).
```

I get the same error in all 4 div's when clicking them.
It refers to http://127.0.0.1:5000/playCard/4, and I there is only 0,1,2,3 in the list.
Why is that and how can I make the clickevent look like this:
onclick="playCard(0)", onclick="playCard(1)", onclick="playCard(2)",onclick="playCard(3)"

The backend server througs "IndexError: list index out of range" because 4 is not what it expects.

Comment: The variable `z` should be explicitly declared with `let` or `var`, for what that's worth. *edit* oh wait, it's worth a lot: declare it with `let`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you click on your div the value of `z` is going to be the last value of your for loop. 
In order to prevent this you need to wrap those lines in a closure.

```
for (let z = 0; z < data.length; z++) {
    (function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.id = 'card'+index;
        iDiv.innerHTML = data[index] + ' - ' + index;
        iDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {playCard(index)}, false); 
        document.getElementById('hand').appendChild(iDiv);
    })(z) 
}
```

For more info about closures have a look to the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)